# How to define a page with multiple search params in SvelteKit?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I want to read out multiple search params in SvelteKit. I don't know how to set up the correct folder structure for the routing. I get a 404 not found error. How can I read out all the search params correctly?

URL

```
http://example.com/profiles/search?name=bob&age=44&job=driver
```

Folder

```
routes/profiles/[search]
```

page.js

```
    export function load({ url }) {
        console.log(' params', url.searchParams);
    }
```

Comment: Are your files named correctly? It should be `+page.svelte` and `+page.js`.

Comment: @H.B. yes the are named correct. It works when I do without the folder [search] and then read out url.searchParams.get(), does this make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`params` are a completely separate thing from query string parameters.

They refer to dynamic elements of the URL path which you don't seem to have here.

You can always read the query parameters without any additional route adjustments, so the route folder/files should just be:

```
routes/profiles/search/+page.svelte
routes/profiles/search/+page.js (or server variants)
```

Though having a dynamic part should not prevent the route from being found, that should just end up with a param having the value `'search'`.